# Resharper command line inspection throws exceptions

Tags: command-line, resharper, teamcity, code-inspection

We use TeamCity as CI server and want to activate code ispection (.Net). If I configure the code inspection I got a lot of errors from inspector. The same if I try to do code inspection with resharper comman line tools.

We have the following project / solution structure

```
/
- Solutions/
    - Solution1/
        - Solution1.sln
        - BuildOutput/
    - Solution2/
        - Solution2.sln
        - BuildOutput
    ...
- Projects/
    - Project1/
        ...
    - Project2/
        ...
```

The projects are configured to allways build in the solution `BuildOutput` directory.

If I execute code inspection like this from the solution directory:

```
C:\Tools\RSCL\inspectcode.exe "Solution1.sln"
```

I got the following output with errors on the command line:

```
JetBrains Inspect Code 9.0 Update 1 
Running in 64-bit mode, .NET runtime 4.0.30319.34014 under Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
C:\Tools\RSCL\inspectcode.exe : Paths relative to drive roots are not supported. Parametername: component Der tats„chliche Wert war \BuildOutput\Debug.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ C:\Tools\RSCL\inspectcode.exe "Solution1.sln"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Paths relative ...ldOutput\Debug.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

--- EXCEPTION #1/2 [ArgumentOutOfRangeException]
Message = "Paths relative to drive roots are not supported."
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
HResult = COR_E_ARGUMENTOUTOFRANGE=80131502
Source = JetBrains.Platform.Util
ParamName = component
ActualValue = \BuildOutput\Debug
StackTraceString = "
  bei JetBrains.Util.FileSystemPath.Combine(String component)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.Impl.CachedProjectItemValue`2.GetValue()
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.ProjectImpl.<.ctor>b__5(ProjectImpl element)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.ProjectImpl.GetOutputFilePath()
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.Build.OutputAssemblies.UpdateOutputAssemblyMvid(IProject project)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.Build.OutputAssemblies.AfterProjectOpenedInternal(IProject project)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.Viewable.<>c__DisplayClass1d`1.<View>b__1b(Lifetime valueLifetime, TValue value)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.ViewableCollection`1.Add(TValue item)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetime.AddBracket(Action FOpening, Action FClosing)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.ProjectManagerBase.OpenProjectInstance(Pair`2 projectInstanceWithLifetime)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.ProjectManagerBase.<>c__DisplayClass8.<EnqueueOpenProjectInstance>b__6()
     bei JetBrains.Util.Logging.Logger.Catch(Action action)
"
--- Outer ---
--- EXCEPTION #2/2 [LoggerException]
Message = "
  Paths relative to drive roots are not supported.
  Parametername: component
  Der tats„chliche Wert war \BuildOutput\Debug.
"
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
InnerException = "Exception #1 at Root.InnerException"
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = "
  bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.Tasks.SolutionLoadTasksSchedulerBase.ExecuteOneTask(SolutionLoadTask task)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.Tasks.SolutionLoadTasksSchedulerBase.DispatchTasks(Boolean background)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.SolutionManagerBase.CreateSolutionInstance(SolutionElement solutionElement, SolutionInstance solutionInstance)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.MsBuild.Internal.MsBuildSolutionManager.<>c__DisplayClass4.<>c__DisplayClass6.<.ctor>b__1()
     bei JetBrains.Threading.ReentrancyGuard.Execute(String name, Action action)
     bei JetBrains.Threading.ReentrancyGuard.ExecuteOrQueue(String name, Action action)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.MsBuild.Internal.MsBuildSolutionManager.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__0(Lifetime msBuildSolutionLifetime, MsBuildSolution msBuildSolution)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetimes.Define(Lifetime lifetime, String id, Action`2 FAtomic, ILogger logger)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.SequentialLifetimes.DefineNext(Action`2 FNext)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.NotifySinks(TValue payload)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.Fire(TValue value, Object cookie)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.FireChange(TValue old, TValue new, Object cookie)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.SetValue(TValue value, Object cookie)
     bei JetBrains.ProjectModel.MsBuild.MsBuildSolutionHost.OpenSolution(FileSystemPath location, IMsBuildSolutionUserProfile userProfile)
     bei JetBrains.CommandLine.InspectCode.Unattended.InspectCodeProductMain.OpenSolution(FileSystemPath solutionFilePath, ILogger logger, MsBuildSolutionHost solutionHost, SolutionsManager solutionsManager, 
IInspectCodeSettings settings)
     bei JetBrains.CommandLine.InspectCode.Unattended.InspectCodeProductMain.Main(IThreading invocator, IShellLocks shellLocks, ILogger logger, IInspectCodeSettings settings, MsBuildSolutionHost solutionHost, 
SolutionsManager solutionsManager, PlatformMana
ger platformManager, ISdkManager sdkManager, IProductCommandLineArguments argumentsRaw, IssuesTypesWriter issuesTypesWriter)
     bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
     bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
     bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
     bei JetBrains.Application.Environment.RunsPublicStaticIntMain.<>c__DisplayClass7.<.ctor>b__0()
     bei JetBrains.Util.Logging.Logger.Catch(Action action)
     bei JetBrains.Threading.JetDispatcher.Closure.Execute()
     bei JetBrains.Threading.JetDispatcher.ProcessQueue()
     bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
     bei MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
     bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
     bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
     bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
     bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
     bei MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
     bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
     bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
     bei MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
     bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
     bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
     bei MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
     bei MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
     bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
     bei JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetimes.Using(Action`1 ?)
     bei JetBrains.Application.Environment.IJetHostEx.RunHostMessageLoop(IComponentContainer containerEnv)
     bei JetBrains.Application.Environment.HostParameters.JetHostParametersCaller.RunMainLoop(ComponentContainer containerEnv)
     bei JetBrains.Application.Environment.JetEnvironment.InternalRun(JetHostParametersCaller host, ComponentContainer containerEnv)
     bei JetBrains.Application.Environment.JetEnvironment.CreateAndRun(Full hostparams)
     bei JetBrains.CommandLine.InspectCode.InspectCodeProgram.Main(Assembly assembly, HostInfo hostInfo, String[] args)
     bei JetBrains.CommandLine.InspectCode.InspectCodeProgram.Main(String[] args)
"
Paths relative to drive roots are not supported. Parametername: component Der tats„chliche Wert war \BuildOutput\Debug.
--- EXCEPTION #1/2 [ArgumentOutOfRangeException]

...
```

I don't understand what is going wrong. The Solutions are all buildable and code inspection from VS works well on the same solutions.

Comment: No. No solution found.

Comment: See below for solution

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Mine was failing because my .csproj did not define the SolutionDir. The relative path error is a red herring so to speak.

Make sure this is in the csproj

```
<SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\..\</SolutionDir>
```